# How to set the background of checked items in a listview in multiple select mode in android

Tags: android

I've a `ListActivity`

```
public class MyActivity extends ListActivity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedstate){
        super.onCreate(savedstate);
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        getListView().setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {


        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            Log.i("xxx", "onPrepareActionMode");
            return false;
        }


        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }


        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }


        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }


        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
            Log.i("xxx", "pos: "+position+", checked: "+checked);
            mode.setTitle(getListView().getCheckedItemCount()+" checked");

        }
    });
    }

}
```

Here I can see the items getting checked but background of checked items is not changing. I know a way how to do it, have your `CustomAdapter` and in `getView()` set the background of the views that are checked. But I believe there is much simpler way to handle it. Could you tell me if there is anyway to achieve it?

Attaching the Screenshot[image]

Comment: please put @Overrides annotation where needed. It helps with readability

Comment: Use a selector xml.. `state_checked="true"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, i got the answer by going through the source code of other app which does that. Set a statelist drawable as background for list item. In selector `state_activated = true` give the background drawable.

Comment: I've been looking for this answer whole day. Thanks!